# Getting issue in union of 2 queries

Tags: mysql, join, union

I am getting an issue in below query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postcodes ON (
        wp_postcodes.post_id = wp_posts.id
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'
        AND TRUNCATE (
            (degrees(acos(sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians('37.090240')) + cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians('37.090240')) * cos(radians(longitude - '-95.712891')))) * 69.09),
            1
            ) <= 400
        AND TRUNCATE (
            (degrees(acos(sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians('37.090240')) + cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians('37.090240')) * cos(radians(longitude - '-95.712891')))) * 69.09),
            1
            ) >= 40
        )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (
        wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'  
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND (   
            (
                meta_key = 'city'
                AND meta_value = 'sports'
                )
            OR (
                meta_key = 'state'
                AND meta_value = 'sports'
                )
            OR post_title = 'sports'
            )
        )
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (
        wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'listingcategory'
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 406
        )

UNION

    DISTINCT
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postcodes ON (
        wp_postcodes.post_id = wp_posts.id
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'
        AND TRUNCATE (
            (degrees(acos(sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians('37.090240')) + cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians('37.090240')) * cos(radians(longitude - '-95.712891')))) * 69.09),
            1
            ) <= 400
        AND TRUNCATE (
            (degrees(acos(sin(radians(latitude)) * sin(radians('37.090240')) + cos(radians(latitude)) * cos(radians('37.090240')) * cos(radians(longitude - '-95.712891')))) * 69.09),
            1
            ) >= 40
        )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (
        wp_postmeta.post_id = wp_posts.id
        AND wp_posts.post_type = 'listing'
        AND wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        AND (
            (
                meta_key = 'city'
                AND meta_value LIKE '%sports%'
                )
            OR (
                meta_key = 'state'
                AND meta_value LIKE '%sports%'
                )
            OR post_title LIKE '%sports%'
            )
        )
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id)
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON (
        wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'listingcategory'
        AND wp_term_taxonomy.term_id = 406
        )
```

here it have 2 queries with union, 1st getting no output but 2nd getting output. And I am performing union of both queries. here should be a result
but I am getting no result. Please suggest what mistake I am doing..

Comment: That's a monster! No-one's likely to want to understand that as is. Please spend some time formatting it to make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: So it's really just the first SELECT statement that you need to analyze since that's the part giving you problems. Have you tried running just the first SELECT statement separately?

Comment: have you error message .. ?  be sure you don't have @mysql...that hide the error message

Comment: Also, without seeing your data, it's really impossible to say why your query isn't giving results (assuming it's not throwing an error). Besides running the first select statement separately, you can also try changing all of the INNER JOIN's to LEFT OUTER JOIN's and doing a SELECT * to see what tables you are joining are spitting out NULLs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reply. 
I have resolved my issue, here UNION is working fine for me instead of UNION DISTINCT. Now my concern has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

UNION operation try to merge the result sets and remove the duplicates. Try UNION ALL and see

Comment: Hello, Thanks for reply.
UNION ALL will provide the output with duplicate result. This will not work for me.

Comment: you can use select distinct after the union SELECT DISTINCT COL1, COL2  FROM (SELECT COL1, COL2 FROM T1 UNION ALL SELECT COL1, CLO2 FROM T2) this will remove the duplicates

Comment: also you can remove all 3 distinct keywords in your original query